# $("#txtquery").attr("disabled","disabled") sets textbox value to blank

Tags: jquery

I want to restrict user to enter values in textbox at particular button click otherwise set disabled false.
If I set `$("#txtquery").attr("disabled","disabled");` it sets text box to blank.
I want to retain the text if readonly is toggled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#txtquery').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$('#txtquery').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

to disallow further editing.